# zsh: escape newline after heredoc in zsh script

Tags: python, shell, escaping, zsh, heredoc

I'm trying to write a zsh script that contains a python 1-liner which takes an argument.

```
#!/bin/zsh

foo_var="foo"

python -c "import sys; print sys.argv" $foo_var
```

(This isn't my actual code but this is the gist of what I was doing.)

That code outputs the following:

```
['-c', 'foo']
```

The one liner got a little longer than I wanted it to, so I put it in a heredoc, like this:

```
#!/bin/zsh

bar_var="bar"

python << EOF    
import sys                                                                                                                                                    
print sys.argv                                                                                                                                                
EOF                                                                                                                                                           
$bar_var
```

(Again, not my actual code but same idea.)

which outputs:

```
['']
./doctest.zsh:14: command not found: bar
```

I need `$bar_var` to be on the line as `python` so it will get passed as an argument, but I can't have anything on the same line as the second 'EOF'. I also can't have anything before the heredoc because python will interpret it as a filename.

Is there a way to work around the mandatory newline after the second EOF, or better yet, is there generally a better way to do this?

(Also this is my first SO post, so please let me know if I've done something wrong in that sense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do what you want:

```
python - $bar_var << EOF 
import sys
print sys.argv
EOF
```